# How does "Community" mark something as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates

How does the "Community ♦" mark something as dupe? I have seen it a few time, but I am unsure how that actually happens. Normally, 5 people (or a mod) will mark something as a dupe. Can a normal user start the process of the Community ♦ user marking a question? If so, is this something I should be doing rather than  marking it myself?

What chain of events must happen for Community ♦ to mark a question?

I just want to make sure I am doing things correctly, as I am still kind of new here (4 months)

Comment: I had the same question a few months ago, I found the answer by searching on meta.SE. In general, for questions that are not Workplace.SE specific, you would usually find answers sooner on meta.SE. There is nothing "wrong" with asking here though.

Comment: I tend to forget that meta.SE exists, ill try to remember to look there in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happened there is someone with under 3k rep flagged suggesting a duplicate (which doesn't actually cast a close vote).

When a question has a suggested duplicate a dialog appears that asks, "did this answer your question?" and if you select "yes" then it is treated as "Community" voting to close.

I've never seen this chain though with a non-3k user suggesting a dup and then being accepted. It makes things look... weird.

Comment: More info [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287763/why-does-this-question-show-as-marked-as-duplicate-by-community)

Comment: And the Meta SE [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930) for it also

Comment: Perfect! that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: In the most recent one you probably [saw](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/97533/i-procrastinated-on-a-project-for-too-long-what-should-i-do) I was the one flagging (less than 3k still) and the OP most probably accepted as he indicated

Comment: Yeah. It's made worse because the "possible duplicate" comment is auto deleted once it is confirmed as a duplicate, too,.

Comment: the most fascinating thing is, asker with [just 15 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285766/165773) can do all this magic of Community dupe-close singlehandedly, just flag their own question as duplicate, reload the question page in browser and accept "this solved my problem". This apparently comes from Stack Overflow where they desperately try anything to tame the problem of too many duplicates flooding it

Comment: "I've never seen this chain though with a non-3k user" - [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930) shows an example of this.

Comment: Are you sure this is specific to lower-rep users flagging as possible duplicates? I thought the asker had the possibility of accepting a duplicate any time somebody flagged or voted. Or do you just mean that this is the only way that "community" can be the _only_ "close-voter"?